# Gesture for the letter i not accepted

Tags: java, android, gestures

I'm developing an android app that displays a letter that the user has to draw. The user then inputs a gesture and if the gesture name matches/mismatches the letter name then a dialog pops up saying either correct or incorrect, offering the user the chance to move on or try again. I created the gestures library for this app with a modified version of gestures builder and everything is working properly except on the letters i and j. The problem seems to be the dot on top of each of these letters. The incorrect message won't even pop up. Is there anyway to get an app to accept a gesture that has two seperate parts?

EDIT: When I leave out the dot at the top the letter is processed as it should be.

Comment: Sure-  write your own custom gesture detector that doesn't stop on the first TOUCH_UP event.  But you'd have to tell us a lot more of how you're doing your gestures to give more help than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to set the android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1".
This specifies the minimum length stroke before it is recognized as a gesture by Android.  The cross of the “t” or dot of the “i” may be difficult to pickup if this is a larger length. So the dot was essentially stopping my app from recognising the letters as gestures. It's all working perfectly now though :)